# AWS Cognito x Facebook - Web Identify Federation - App Domains

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I configured Web Identify Federation between AWS Cognito and Facebook and I'm getting the following error message when I tried to authenticate:

> "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

I'm struggling to find out which is the correct URL I have to add in the App Domains.
I tried the URL for the static-website on S3 and its CloudFront URL, and it doesn't work.
Does it need a proper domain name to work?

I'm just looking for an example.

Thank you,

Carlos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have configured Facebook as an IdP directly in Cognito userpool then the URL you need to add in your app would be:
https://your-user-pool-domain/oauth2/idpresponse

See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social.html) documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

To add more information, [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-domain.html) is how you set up a domain and [configure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-settings.html) your app.